# How to run laravel cronjob in local linux system?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, lamp

I have a `cronjob` with name `changeflag`. I can use following terminal command to execute this `cronjob` in local.

```
php artisan changeflag
```

In hosting server, I can easily set the execution of console command with cron job.

Is it possible to run above command periodically in local system in Linux automatically as in server ?

or

We have to execute above command through terminal for every test ?

I am using **LAMP**.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/. it has the complete process of creating laravel based cron jobs

Comment: And this [one](https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel) as well !

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If you local linux installation has cron installed (hard to imagine it has not...), it would work exactly the same. Have you tried it?

Comment: do you want to add this cron in crontab?

Comment: Is it possible to configure a scheduled tasks on two machines runing the same operating system and same edployed software to carry out the same function? Yes. Have you tried? Did it fail? What is your problem?

Comment: I have created a cron job. with `php artisan changeflag` it works perfectly but i want automatic exection of this command

Comment: @ShahrozeNawaz I've already visited there but I don't understand how to setup on local environment

Comment: Properly configured cron job automatically executes the command as scheduled.

Comment: @AlexBlex So, what should I do for this ?

Comment: If you *have created a cron job* and *it works perfectly* there is nothing to do but delete the question.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to add your project's cron jobs in crontab, just add them in crontab file:

change editor to nano (optional)

```
setenv EDITOR nano
```

open crontab file

```
crontab -e
```

add this line

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

replace `path-to-your-project` with the real path and the cron will be executed automatically.
If this doesn't work, replace `php` with full php path. To find the whole path just type in command line `which php`.

For more info read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling)